# ODE inside a loop in R

Tags: r

I'm new to programming and specially R. I find sometimes things easier to get yet more complex to give than Matlab. I'm trying to recreate a loop that I already have in a "script.m" but I haven't been able to get anything on R.
Could anybody please explain me how to run the following for three times this?...

Thanks in advance for any help provided

```
pars  <- c(...)

times <- seq(ti, tf, delta)

state <- c(S = 50, X = 20, P = 0.5)   

SOLVE <- function(pars) { 

    derivs <- function(time, state, pars) {

        with(as.list(c(state, pars)), {
         .
         .
         .
            return(list(c(St, Xt, Pt)))

        })

    }

    return(as.data.frame(ode(y = state, times = times, func = derivs, parms = pars)))  
}


for(i in seq(ti, tf-span, span)) {

     times <- seq(i, i+span, delta)  

     out   <- SOLVE(pars) 

     state <- c(state[1], tail(out[3], 1), tail(out[4], 1))

 }
```

The error i get is:

> Error in checkInput(y, times, func, rtol, atol, jacfunc, tcrit, hmin,  : 
>     `y' must be numeric

Comment: I'm assuming this is working fine for at least one loop iteration, and then is broken after you've tried to update `state`?  You should `cat()` on state in the loop to see what it's being assigned to.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment. Try:

```
state <- c(state[1], tail(out[[3]], 1), tail(out[[4]], 1))
```

The way you have it set up, `out` is a data.frame. `out[3]` returns a data.frame with one column. `tail(out[3],1)` returns a data.frame with one row and one column (but still a data.frame). When you combine these using, e.g.,

```
c(state[1],tail(out[3],1),...)
```

you generate a *list*, not a numeric, which is causing the error.

If you reference, e.g., `out[[3]]` you return a *vector* which elements are the third column of `out`. This is because, in R, a data.frame is by definition a list of vectors, so `out[[3]]` returns the third element (vector) in that list.

Comment: Dear jlhoward,

Thank you for the explanation. Now, in "out" I get the values for the last iteration, would you now how to get all the values for all three iterations to plot the whole date from 0 to 12? 

    for(i in seq(ti, tf-span, span)) {
        times <- seq(i, i+span, delta)        # sampling time. N/P = 10
        out   <- SOLVE(pars) 
        state <- c(S = state[[1]], X = tail(out[[3]], 1), P = tail(out[[4]], 1))
        X0    <- state[[2]]
        plot(out$time, out$S)
        points(out$time, out$X)
        points(out$time, out$P)
    }

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to answer this. You do not define `ti`, `tf'` or `span`, or `delta`,  for instance. The code in your comment will produce a plot for each iteration of the loop. In what way is the desired result different?